# Angular directive binding isolated scope with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The value of score_stats in the directive is always undefined, and in the parent scope the stats variable has the correct value. What am I doing wrong?

I have this code in the template (and fixtures_stats is an array):

```
div(ng-repeat="stats in fixture_stats")
  scenario-analysis(score_stats="stats")
```

This code in the directive:

```
{                                                                    
  templateUrl: '/' + appVersion + '/directives/scenario-analysis.html',                                                                                                                                              
  scope:{
      score_stats:'=score_stats'
  },
  controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log('directive $scope.score_stats: ' + $scope.score_stats +
                  ', $scope.$parent.stats: ' + $scope.$parent.stats);
  },                                                                               
};
```

This code in the directive template:

```
h3 Scenarios for {{ score_stats.score1 }}-{{ score_stats.score2 }} score combo
```

In the console I get:

```
directive $scope.score_stats: undefined, $scope.$parent.stats: [object Object]
directive $scope.score_stats: undefined, $scope.$parent.stats: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use an expression for `score_stats` attribute:

```
div(ng-repeat="stats in fixture_stats")
  scenario-analysis(score_stats="stats")
```

Then in directive definition instead of `scope_stats` scope property will become camelCase'ed:

```
scope: {
    scoreStats: '='
}
```

so in directive template you need to change to:

```
Scenarios for {{ scoreStats.score1 }}-{{ scoreStats.score2 }} score combo
```

Comment: No change: score_stats is still undefined in the directive

Comment: There is some confusion with `_` separators in scope attribute names. I would recommend to use common snake-case for predictable results. See updated answer.